# CKEditor Configuration, why it remove id in span attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, drupal, ckeditor

my ckeditor has this configuration: config.allowedContent = true

If I insert this code into my editor:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
 <input type="text" name="LastName" class="form-control" id="LastName">
        <div class="help-block animated fadeInDown">
        <span id="errLastNameMsg"></span>
       </div>
    </div>

this is a simple id <span id="errLastNameMsg"></span> with span content.

After Ckeditor compile it is.
 <div class="col-xs-12"><input class="form-control" id="LastName" 
    name="LastName" type="text" /> 
    <div class="help-block animated fadeInDown">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>


It Strip <span id="errLastNameMsg"></span> with &nbsp;

thanks in advance for your's solution.
```

Comment: Try `config.extraAllowedContent = '*[id]';`. Disabling all filters is not a good idea

Comment: private CkeditorConfig = {
  allowedContent: true,
  extraAllowedContent:'*[id]',
  protectedSource:/<i[^>]*><\/i>/g
 }

I also used that but can't help for me.

Comment: try to add a &nbsp; into span , i think the span is deleted because is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKEditor has an option for ignoring elements if empty: [CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dtd-property-S-removeEmpty)

By default, empty span elements are removed.

Use this to allow empty span elements:

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.span = 0;
```